# How to download the notebook from watson studio desktop

Tags: watson-studio-desktop

How does one download a notebook from Watson Studio Desktop?

We are trying to test the notebooks from watson studio desktop to work with WML Server.We want to download this notebooks so that we can put them in github for our users to be able to access.

However, there are no options under the File menu, or the action menu when looking at the project assets.

Answer (score 1):

There is no download notebook option in WSD from the notebook page.  To retrieve the notebook you need to find the notebook in the Application data folder.

From the project you can go to the View folder link and navigate to the project assets.

Documented here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBFT6_1.1.0/wsd/files.html